# Parse string to JSon Object

Tags: java, android, json

I have this String :

```
{
\"content\": {
    \"subscribe_xsrf_token\": \"IcEWvGoQM-sqgeQ7moZrvrpv9uR8MTM3MjMxODI0OUAxMzcyMjMxODQ5\",
    \"ad_instream\": {
        \"message\": \"\",
        \"encrypted_id\": \"\",
        \"tracking\": {
            \"impression\": [
                \"http: \\\/\\\/pubads.g.doubleclick.net\\\/pagead\\\/adview?ai=Bo6s3qZjKUdKfJavGsQf0goHoBu3Fn_0EAAAAEAEgADgAWKWn-_lbYPmCgICcEIIBF2NhLXB1Yi0yNjE0NjY2MjYxNTc5NzQxsgEYd3d3LmRjbGstZGVmYXVsdC1yZWYuY29tugEJZ2ZwX2ltYWdlyAEJ2gEgaHR0cDovL3d3dy5kY2xrLWRlZmF1bHQtcmVmLmNvbS_AAgLgAgDqAiM0MDYxL21vYmkueXRwd2F0Y2gubXVzaWMvbWFpbl8xMDQ4MfgC_NEekAOEB5gD4AOoAwHQBJBO4AQBoAYg2AYC\\u0026sigh=5WBHzDSiaTs\\u0026adurl=http: \\\/\\\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\\\/pagead\\\/imgad\\\/879366\\\/dot.gif?142424255\"
            ]
        },
        \"title\": \"\",
        \"stream_url\": \"\",
        \"clickthrough\": \"\",
        \"duration\": 0,
        \"companion_image\": \"\",
        \"source\": \"\"
    },
    \"should_prompt_merge_identity\": false,
    \"subscription_state\": {
        \"is_subscribed\": false,
        \"subscribe_url\": {
            \"channel_id\": \"UC20vb-R_px4CguHzzBPhoyQ\",
            \"url\": \"\\\/channel_post?feature=watch\\u0026action_subscribe=1\"
        },
        \"show_button\": true
    },
    \"ptracking\": \"\\\/\\\/www.youtube.com\\\/ptracking?oid=yZJtHRi2SvzOOKZfbA-GRA\\u0026pltype=content\\u0026video_id=YVkUvmDQ3HY\\u0026ptchn=EminemVEVO\\u0026ptk=vevo\",
    \"featured_playlist_id\": \"9TPK2s-Y1-sWMoxl6bV2oIIb3I8GwE9G\",
    \"watch_branding\": {
        \"watermark\": \"http: \\\/\\\/www.vevo.com\\\/?utm_source=youtube\\u0026utm_medium=player\\u0026utm_campaign=logo,
        http: \\\/\\\/s.ytimg.com\\\/yts\\\/img\\\/watermark\\\/vevo_watermark-vflyal4o8.png\",
        \"banner_style\": \"phone\",
        \"banner_click_url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/vevo.ly\\\/17mWVR9\",
        \"banner_url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i1.ytimg.com\\\/u\\\/20vb-R_px4CguHzzBPhoyQ\\\/mobile_watch_banner.jpg?v=51c290bf\"
    },
    \"channel_subscriber_count\": 5127791,
    \"allow_comments\": true,
    \"sentiment_xsrf_token\": \"XTsxJAb-TWLPkOcOSIklfpWcz8p8MTM3MjMxODI0OUAxMzcyMjMxODQ5\",
    \"pyv_ping_url\": null,
    \"allow_ratings\": true,
    \"branding\": \"vevo\",
    \"next_url\": \"\\\/related?v=YVkUvmDQ3HY\\u0026page=2\",
    \"featured_playlist_name\": \"FForYou\",
    \"related_videos\": [
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"9dcVOmEQzKA\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/9dcVOmEQzKA\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=csTI8oqsUJguD5cWFajcOyqVbb4\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=9dcVOmEQzKA\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-JustLoseIt\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 06\",
            \"view_count\": \"67,
            054,
            626\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"1wYNFfgrXTI\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/1wYNFfgrXTI\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=z2Qx_ArjHHa5fUpKRMZT3wFrxb4\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 80,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=1wYNFfgrXTI\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-WhenI'mGone\",
            \"duration\": \"6: 09\",
            \"view_count\": \"150,
            353,
            417\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"eJO5HU_7_1w\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/eJO5HU_7_1w\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=8tjo7YrMaPIfo4sRG8dnc1jlNw4\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 160,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=eJO5HU_7_1w\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-TheRealSlimShady(Edited)\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 28\",
            \"view_count\": \"42,
            847,
            951\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"D4hAVemuQXY\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/D4hAVemuQXY\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=eonhN9WV1LcnyPmiIHvkhNFh1Mc\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 240,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=D4hAVemuQXY\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-SingForTheMoment\",
            \"duration\": \"5: 28\",
            \"view_count\": \"51,
            781,
            830\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"VA770wpLX-Q\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/VA770wpLX-Q\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=LKBiDjo8f8InG_Y3gpU_fkMwWpY\",
            \"public_name\": \"DrDreVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 320,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=related\\u0026v=VA770wpLX-Q\",
            \"related_feature\": \"related\",
            \"title\": \"Dr.Dre-INeedADoctor(Explicit)ft.Eminem,
            SkylarGrey\",
            \"duration\": \"7: 37\",
            \"view_count\": \"130,
            761,
            821\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"LoQYw49saqc\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/LoQYw49saqc\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=StjTR1mMz-lhcWEiE91jRG-v988\",
            \"public_name\": \"emimusic\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 400,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=related\\u0026v=LoQYw49saqc\",
            \"related_feature\": \"related\",
            \"title\": \"Gorillaz-ClintEastwood\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 29\",
            \"view_count\": \"44,
            156,
            267\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"RSdKmX2BH7o\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/RSdKmX2BH7o\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=vWWafsVrB6UkAZbSXmZarUg71pU\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 480,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=RSdKmX2BH7o\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-WeMadeYou\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 44\",
            \"view_count\": \"65,
            333,
            148\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"otCpCn0l4Wo\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/otCpCn0l4Wo\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=45clre28Rd1_1yqYjfmuMavvJhI\",
            \"public_name\": \"emimusic\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 560,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=related\\u0026v=otCpCn0l4Wo\",
            \"related_feature\": \"related\",
            \"title\": \"MCHammer-UCan'tTouchThis\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 38\",
            \"view_count\": \"59,
            311,
            148\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"lexLAjh8fPA\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/lexLAjh8fPA\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=D10LzAJ6_HHoTnHlZ2cLVokUEmY\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 640,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=lexLAjh8fPA\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-LikeToySoldiers\",
            \"duration\": \"5: 24\",
            \"view_count\": \"116,
            269,
            743\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"lgT1AidzRWM\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/lgT1AidzRWM\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=4K-3W82kQ5T2JGYMYTTDeIUoZ3g\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 720,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=lgT1AidzRWM\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-Beautiful\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 15\",
            \"view_count\": \"159,
            731,
            519\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"JByDbPn6A1o\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/JByDbPn6A1o\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=uGrukuRmu9MnxEpju1R8Qik8NL4\",
            \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vt?cids=9dcVOmEQzKA,
                1wYNFfgrXTI,
                eJO5HU_7_1w,
                D4hAVemuQXY,
                VA770wpLX-Q,
                LoQYw49saqc,
                RSdKmX2BH7o,
                otCpCn0l4Wo,
                lexLAjh8fPA,
                lgT1AidzRWM,
                JByDbPn6A1o\\u0026w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=jMTwlTEmaSnnuYuYc7mtzdcXDho\",
                \"height\": 880,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 800,
                \"thumb_width\": 120,
                \"width\": 128,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"stitched\": 1
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?feature=relmfu\\u0026v=JByDbPn6A1o\",
            \"related_feature\": \"relmfu\",
            \"title\": \"Eminem-SpaceBound\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 25\",
            \"view_count\": \"90,
            745,
            391\"
        }
    ],
    \"featured_videos\": [
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"5TUIciKQzxI\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/5TUIciKQzxI\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=w9zK7mNwbfsEOOLbTFAitgBSEbY\",
            \"public_name\": \"DisclosureVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/5TUIciKQzxI\\\/default.jpg?w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=zJyRsaoan-J6bpr978_oyj5NhwU\",
                \"height\": 72,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"stitched\": 0,
                \"width\": 120,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"thumb_width\": 120
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=5TUIciKQzxI\",
            \"title\": \"Disclosure-FForYou\",
            \"encrypted_set_video_id\": \"56B44F6D10557CC6\",
            \"duration\": \"4: 10\",
            \"view_count\": \"322,
            052\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"3p6C_KFOmGA\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/3p6C_KFOmGA\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=bOh8IPntvfJyg5gMzFTMpVCG9ws\",
            \"public_name\": \"kkokevevo\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/3p6C_KFOmGA\\\/default.jpg?w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=XV77xNAJzmQzMj73C3rsES3QVKU\",
                \"height\": 72,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"stitched\": 0,
                \"width\": 120,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"thumb_width\": 120
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=3p6C_KFOmGA\",
            \"title\": \"MyTime-BehindTheScenes(XperiaAccess)\",
            \"encrypted_set_video_id\": \"289F4A46DF0A30D2\",
            \"duration\": \"2: 50\",
            \"view_count\": \"2,
            490\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"vrnwyN0jr-Y\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/vrnwyN0jr-Y\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=8f_x95WXJ_s3cTOBYhcKMZTQEVE\",
            \"public_name\": \"WilkinsonVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/vrnwyN0jr-Y\\\/default.jpg?w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=UNP5tgKMXFjM-MVO7loRdUvYFOQ\",
                \"height\": 72,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"stitched\": 0,
                \"width\": 120,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"thumb_width\": 120
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=vrnwyN0jr-Y\",
            \"title\": \"Wilkinson-Heartbeatft.PMoney,
            Arlissa\",
            \"encrypted_set_video_id\": \"017208FAA85233F9\",
            \"duration\": \"3: 25\",
            \"view_count\": \"61,
            037\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"byPRmtaEwxk\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/byPRmtaEwxk\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=hLMewtIKszLHi29XQWaWisQnoDI\",
            \"public_name\": \"ProfessorGreenVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/byPRmtaEwxk\\\/default.jpg?w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=VNgKOeBYOTkFXMuVNJCAX-qRDX4\",
                \"height\": 72,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"stitched\": 0,
                \"width\": 120,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"thumb_width\": 120
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=byPRmtaEwxk\",
            \"title\": \"ProfessorGreen-AreYouGettingEnough?ft.MilesKane\",
            \"encrypted_set_video_id\": \"52152B4946C2F73F\",
            \"duration\": \"3: 06\",
            \"view_count\": \"357,
            640\"
        },
        {
            \"encrypted_id\": \"OfO4DYcExpU\",
            \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/OfO4DYcExpU\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=jb4aD-Litllh-Oz4G9Rj-Ed9Zec\",
            \"public_name\": \"wearemonstaVEVO\",
            \"playability\": \"NO_PREFETCH\",
            \"thumbnail_info\": {
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/OfO4DYcExpU\\\/default.jpg?w=120\\u0026h=72\\u0026sigh=7eskNhBWKOP3kDy23m91k4v2w7Y\",
                \"height\": 72,
                \"posx\": 0,
                \"posy\": 0,
                \"stitched\": 0,
                \"width\": 120,
                \"thumb_height\": 72,
                \"thumb_width\": 120
            },
            \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=OfO4DYcExpU\",
            \"title\": \"MONSTA-MONSTABitesVolume7\",
            \"encrypted_set_video_id\": \"090796A75D153932\",
            \"duration\": \"3: 31\",
            \"view_count\": \"24,
            413\"
        }
    ],
    \"video\": {
        \"encrypted_id\": \"YVkUvmDQ3HY\",
        \"thumbnail_for_watch\": \"http: \\\/\\\/i.ytimg.com\\\/vi\\\/YVkUvmDQ3HY\\\/hqdefault.jpg?w=320\\u0026h=192\\u0026sigh=BfDjKngCLfUuZBlDeclL4z7hiIM\",
        \"public_name\": \"EminemVEVO\",
        \"profile_url\": \"\\\/user\\\/EminemVEVO\",
        \"playability\": \"PLAY_OK\",
        \"description\": \"MusicvideobyEminemperformingWithoutMe.(C)2002AftermathRecords\",
        \"thumbnail_info\": null,
        \"player_type\": \"html5fs\",
        \"comment_count\": 122787,
        \"dislikes_num\": 7896,
        \"user_image_url\": \"\\\/\\\/i1.ytimg.com\\\/i\\\/20vb-R_px4CguHzzBPhoyQ\\\/1.jpg?v=ba8e09\",
        \"watch_link\": \"\\\/watch?v=YVkUvmDQ3HY\",
        \"time_created_text\": \"Jun16,
        2009\",
        \"longform\": false,
        \"title\": \"Eminem-WithoutMe\",
        \"fmt_stream_map\": [
            {
                \"fallback_host\": \"tc.v10.cache2.c.youtube.com\",
                \"type\": \"video\\\/mp4;codecs=\\\"avc1.42001E,
                mp4a.40.2\\\"\",
                \"quality\": \"medium\",
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/r2---sn-cx1x9-ua8s.c.youtube.com\\\/videoplayback?id=615914be60d0dc76\\u0026upn=ZLjj8oNyCro\\u0026cp=U0hWR1JQU19LT0NONl9KSldDOnlWdDVYeGNkcWx4\\u0026el=watch\\u0026newshard=yes\\u0026ipbits=8\\u0026key=yt1\\u0026gcr=il\\u0026yms=xYu0Zzbcsjw\\u0026ip=109.65.186.62\\u0026ms=au\\u0026mt=1372231783\\u0026mv=m\\u0026dnc=1\\u0026expire=1372255265\\u0026itag=18\\u0026sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire\\u0026fexp=921047%2C928201%2C901208%2C929123%2C929915%2C929906%2C929907%2C929125%2C925714%2C929917%2C929919%2C931202%2C912512%2C912515%2C912521%2C906838%2C904488%2C906840%2C931910%2C931913%2C932227%2C904830%2C919373%2C933701%2C904122%2C900816%2C926403%2C909421%2C912711%2C935000\\u0026source=youtube\\u0026app=youtube_mobile\\u0026sver=3\\u0026signature=8BA53131CBB3E14D834E92B6BDD955C00F2A61F7.C4F91054DA7D34C92F34F52C7D4581EA0276D6D3\\u0026ratebypass=yes\",
                \"itag\": \"18\"
            },
            {
                \"fallback_host\": \"tc.v24.cache2.c.youtube.com\",
                \"type\": \"video\\\/3gpp;codecs=\\\"mp4v.20.3,
                mp4a.40.2\\\"\",
                \"quality\": \"small\",
                \"url\": \"http: \\\/\\\/r2---sn-cx1x9-ua8s.c.youtube.com\\\/videoplayback?id=615914be60d0dc76\\u0026upn=ZLjj8oNyCro\\u0026cp=U0hWR1JQU19LT0NONl9KSldDOnlWdDVYeGNkcWx4\\u0026el=watch\\u0026newshard=yes\\u0026ipbits=8\\u0026key=yt1\\u0026gcr=il\\u0026yms=xYu0Zzbcsjw\\u0026ip=109.65.186.62\\u0026ms=au\\u0026mt=1372231783\\u0026mv=m\\u0026dnc=1\\u0026expire=1372255265\\u0026itag=36\\u0026sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire\\u0026fexp=921047%2C928201%2C901208%2C929123%2C929915%2C929906%2C929907%2C929125%2C925714%2C929917%2C929919%2C931202%2C912512%2C912515%2C912521%2C906838%2C904488%2C906840%2C931910%2C931913%2C932227%2C904830%2C919373%2C933701%2C904122%2C900816%2C926403%2C909421%2C912711%2C935000\\u0026source=youtube\\u0026app=youtube_mobile\\u0026sver=3\\u0026signature=4842A9458189F2C883B8C7B31748DC92780FB25D.2F6906EDC26D4F701CABE911557F4F42FD86D2BF\\u0026ratebypass=yes\",
                \"itag\": \"36\"
            }
        ],
        \"length_seconds\": 300,
        \"duration\": \"5: 00\",
        \"likes_num\": 335857,
        \"view_count\": \"114,
        060,
        393\"
    }
},
\"build_id\": 1371854714,
\"result\": \"ok\",
\"build_signature\": \"en: 900816,
901208,
904122,
904488,
904830,
906838,
906840,
909421,
912512,
912515,
912521,
912711,
919373,
921047,
925714,
926403,
928201,
929123,
929125,
929906,
929907,
929915,
929917,
929919,
931202,
931910,
931913,
932227,
933701,
935000\",
\"signed_in_username\": \"\",
\"conn\": \"wifi\"
}
```

And i try to parsi it into `JSONObject` with :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSON);
```

And i execute this command i get Exception(Null exception)

Comment: check if its a valid json from http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace. Additionally, what is `JSON`? is that the string?

Comment: I suspent that `JSON` is `null`

Comment: JSON is the json string

Comment: This is not a valid JSON object .

Comment: with the above JSON Object what you want to do.what problem you are facing with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to paste your string but it seems it's wrong..There are many errors: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

For instance: `http:\\\/\\\/pubads...` should be `http://pubads`